# Can I use Superlab and related software on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, windows

I am a Windows user. I want to use Ubuntu, but I am worried that I might not be able to use science-related software like SuperLab, of which there is no Linux version available.

In such circumstances, what to do?

Comment: I recommend doing a search at WineHQ under Apps to see if people have tried the applications you need and what compatibility rating they give it. http://appdb.winehq.org/index.php

Answer (score 2):

I've just tested it in wine, and it works fine.

The only thing you need to do is download the installer and install wine as [the previous answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/377434/527764) says.

Then, run the installer by right-clicking and selecting **Open With > Wine**

Whenever you need some Windows program run in GNU/Linux you can have a look at this website, [WineHQ](http://appdb.winehq.org/).

There's an extensive database of applications with different levels of compatibility. Some of them (like your program) run out of the box, some others need a little tweaking to make them work. You can find help reading the reviews that other users have done.
I've just sent a review for SuperLab 5.0.0, but it won't be available yet because the maintainers of the website need to verify my review before making it public.

Hope it helps, good  luck!

Answer (score 1):

Windows software can often be used on Ubuntu if you install and run it with Wine & PlayOnLinux.

These applications provide a compatibility layer to allow most Windows software to run on Linux.

To install Wine

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

To install PlayOnLinux

```
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

After installing either one of these, simply select your Windows software and open it. The remaining installation process is the same as in Windows.